# Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: v3.0.0-beta.3: release: not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have recently updated my helm version to v3.0.0-beta. I need to revert back to the helm version to 2. When i tried to switch to the helm version 2, it s spitting an error like "Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: v3.0.0-beta.3: release: not found".

**Helm version:**

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.0.0-beta.3", GitCommit:"5cb923eecbe80d1ad76399aee234717c11931d9a", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.12.9"}
```

Command tried to uninstall : `helm reset`

Also tried `brew uninstall helm` and `helm reset --force`

Error:

> "Error: uninstall: Release not loaded: v3.0.0-beta.3: release: not
>   found"

Is there anyway to downgrade Helm version from 3 to 2...?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been resolved.. Download the stable version from 
[helm v2.15.2](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases?after=v3.0.0-rc.1)

and then find the helm binary in the unpacked directory, and move it to its desired destination (mv linux-amd64/helm /usr/local/bin/helm.

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.15.2", GitCommit:"8dce272473e5f2a7bf58ce79bb5c3691db54c96b", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a command to rollback to the last successful release. You need to define target release version as 0:
`helm rollback <RELEASE> 0`

More details can be found under [this github thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1796).

Please let me know if that helped.